# Projectile motion with only time and initial speed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

So I was trying to solve this problem:

> An elf shoots an arrow 25.0 m/s horizontally at a target. To his disbelief, the arrow hits .260 meters below the bulls eye of the target. How far away is the target?

I tried to get started by using y = y(initial) + V(initial)y*t - (1/2) *gt^2

-0.26 = Vy*t - 4.9t^2

I couldn't figure out what was the range just with the initial horizontal speed or the time

I don't know how to do this problem with the two pieces of information I was provided, does anyone know how to start it?

Comment: I would start with a drawing of a horizontal triangle, with the .260 metres as the base. And then fill in the other info I had. I would also visit www.physicsclassroom.com as they have related problems on vectors

Comment: There are no triangles here. The path is a parabola.

Comment: Don't confused the length of the arc with the distance to the target and then it is just the two equations.  The time to drop .26 meters and the distance the arrow travels in that time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two motions involved here:  horizontal and vertical.

Looking at the vertical motion, you have the initial vertical velocity, the vertical distance, and, assuming it is an Earthly elf, the vertical acceleration.  So you should be able to find the other two parameters of the vertical motion.

For the horizontal motion, you have the acceleration  (none) and the initial velocity.

What parameter from the vertical aspect of the motion transfers over into the horizontal motion?

Comment: The parameter that is shared by both motions is time

Answer (score 1):

[image: Arrow trajectory]

The arrow undergoes two types of motion that are *independent of each other*:

**1.** Motion in $x$-direction:

$$x=v_0t$$

So that: $$\Delta x=v_0\Delta t,\tag{1}$$

where $\Delta t$ is the flight time.

**2.** Motion in $y$-direction:

The arrow has no initial velocity in the $y$-direction but does **fall to earth**, so that:

$$y=\Delta y-\frac12 gt^2$$

So:

$$0=\Delta y-\frac12 g\Delta t^2\tag{2}$$

$(1)$ and $(2)$  gives you a set of two simultaneous equations from which $\Delta x$ can be calculated because $\Delta y$ and $v_0$ are known quantities.